# querySelector to select the closest parent for h1 and p+p elements - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

**EDIT**
The structure is unknown - it should work for any news site, where there is a container/wrapper, that contains h1 and p+p (everything related to the main article of that page)

**What I want can also be achieved with**

```
let story = document.querySelector('p+p').parentElement;
while(!story.querySelector('h1')){
    story = story.parentElement;
}
console.log(story);
```

### But I'm wondersing if there's a better solution?

Every news article has h1 tag and paragraphs with text. I'm wondering if it's possible to write a querySelector that will **select the closest parent/container element that contains both h1 and p+p**. The trick is that it should work with *any* news website...

---

when I write

```
document.body.querySelector('* h1')
```

I can get h1 container, but there's might be multiple h1 tags on the page according to HTML5

*I know about querySelectorAll but this will not help in my case*

---

when I write

```
document.body.querySelector('* p+p').parentElement
```

I can get container for article body with paragraphs of text

---

My question is if it's possible to combine those two examples into a single query? (w/o loop and multiple querys)
Something like...

```
document.body.querySelector('* ~ h1 ~ p+p')
document.body.querySelector('* h1 p+p')
```

...but workable

Comment: have you looked at [`Element#closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: you haven't tagged jQuery for this. Is a jQuery solution ok?

Comment: I prefer to stay away from jQuery nowadays, but if there's a jQuery solution maybe it could be somehow ported to vanillaJS?

Comment: either Element#closest() doesn't work in my case or I'm doing it wrong :(

Comment: Sorry misread your requirement, thought you needed H1 which was a parent. The only problem with your code is you put a general sibling selector (`~`) where it wasnt needed remove it and it should work: `document.querySelector('* h1 ~ p+p').parentElement`

Comment: This is why javascript is a programmable language. To do this sort of work. Why can't you just find the parent if those two elements exist as you have shown?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I've tried `document.querySelector('* h1 ~ p+p').parentElemen` - didn't work;
---------
@Rob `let story = document.querySelector('* p+p').parentElement;
while(!story.querySelector('h1')){
    story = story.parentElement;
}
console.log(story);` works as desired - just wondering if it's possible to achieve same without loop and other whistles

Comment: In what way does it not work? Works perfectly fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/5s9wowxx/

Comment: @PatrickEvans case: open http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-42623651 (or any other news website - make sure you opened article page - not a home page), then open console and paste your code `document.querySelector('* h1 ~ p+p').parentElement` then paste my code `let story = document.querySelector('* p+p').parentElement;
while(!story.querySelector('h1')){
    story = story.parentElement;
}
console.log(story);` - this is how I want it to work, just w/o loop and multiple querys (if posible)

Comment: @PatrickEvans your code will not work if you wrap the p tags inside a div..

Comment: Yes I've noticed. @OlehMelnyk you need to edit your question to include example structures of the elements you are wanting to target. We shouldn't have to guess or visit external websites to find this information. Also since your elements are not directly related to each other the closest solution is what you are already doing.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not giving examples here because everybody will write solutions that work only for those provided cases... moreover, the structure is unknown - that's the tricky part, but if my solution with while loop is ok then let it be - thought I was missing something really simple to get it in a single query

Comment: @Patrick Evans: The entire point of this question is that you don't have to guess, there is no point guessing, and the desired solution needs to work for all cases. The objective is highlighted in bold: "**select the closest parent/container element that contains both h1 and p+p**" It's pretty self-explanatory. The asker just wants to know if there is a more elegant way to do the same thing that can be done with the first snippet of JS.

Comment: To the asker: if there is more than one such closest ancestor, as in the .block examples in Bhuwan Bhatt's answer, do you want 1) only the first of these 2) all of them, or 3) their closest common ancestor? Your code assumes #1.

Comment: @BoltClock in a few words, what I'm trying to make is a news reading app, since native Apple News/Microsoft MSN/Google News didn't work in my country; my app will read RSS/Atom feed, visit each article page and get meta info from there + article content - that's why I need a selector, that will find and select the article container; in theory, if there are more that one such container, then I need the biggest one, as the rest/smalest containers probably will be for "similar articles" section

Comment: That's a bit more challenging. You can't guarantee that the main (I assume that's what you mean by "biggest") article in an article page will always be the first (or nth) element that contains both h1 and p+p. But if what you have works for you, then it's the best you've got, as I state in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jQuery solution.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('.block').each(function(e) {
  if ($(this).find('h4').length > 0 && $(this).find('p+p').length > 0) {
    console.log('block ' + (e + 1))
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block vv">
  <h4>heading</h4>
  <p>para1</p>
  <p>para2</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h4>heading</h4>
  <p>para1</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h4>heading</h4>
  <p>para1</p>
  <p>para2</p>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: sorry, but this will not work in my case - check page like this http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-42623651 (ideally, the code should work with any news website) - this page contains multiple article intros and one main article - what I'm looking for is a code that will return main article container only - does this makes sense?

Comment: just open any news website, like bbc/cnn/whatever - then open any article and paste this into console `let story = document.querySelector('* p+p').parentElement;
while(!story.querySelector('h1')){
    story = story.parentElement;
}
console.log(story);` <- this result I'm looking for, but without a loop, of possible

Comment: He asked for a vanilla javascript solution, not jquery, unless you convert it to plain javascript.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if it's possible to combine those two examples into a single query?

tl;dr: No, it's not. Certainly not today, and probably not anytime soon. If you're not interested in anything beyond a practical answer, this is all you need to know; everything past this paragraph is background information pertaining to a feature that doesn't exist in the standard yet.

---

It depends on what you mean by "a single query". Do you mean "a single assignment"? If so, the `:has()` pseudo-class [from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector), slated for standardization [in Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), will help tremendously:

```
// In jQuery: $('p+p').closest(':has(h1)')
let story = document.querySelector('p+p').closest(':has(h1)');
```

But notice that it's used in conjunction with [`Element#closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), and furthermore, `:has()` is not supported natively yet, and there are no plans to implement it in any browser in the near future. So if jQuery is not an option, what you have is the best you've got for a long while.

If by "a single query" you mean "a single selector", then the answer is no, because it's not possible to write a selector matching the closest common ancestor of two or more descendants. The closest would be `:has(h1):has(p+p)`, but that will match *every* such ancestor, starting with the innermost of these and leading all the way up to the root element. There is no selector for matching just the innermost of these.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the website you provided just use a child and sibling selector. The following will work.:

```
window.document.querySelector("*>h1, * p+p").parentNode
```

It selects all elements with an h1 and all elements with multiple p tags. I tried it onthe page you provided and it produced the same result as your JS code.

A few additional notes, since you didn't specify jquery I gave you a JavaScript solution. Currently there is no parent selector or querySelector so parentNode is the closest thing to that. Lastly, your original solution specified article (and not div like the page has). If you want that, just swap out div for article.

Comment: the trick is that I don't know if there will be a div, article, section or something else... and I want it to work with any site. Also, your solution does not include the h1

Comment: basically, it does the same as in my original post:
`document.body.querySelector('* p+p').parentElement`
just work with divs only instead of any possible container

Comment: an updated version `window.document.querySelector("* > h1+p+p").parentNode` didn't work :(

Comment: I think I understand now.

Comment: `window.document.querySelector("*>h1, * p+p").parentNode` works in some cases, but it some it fails, like here https://tsn.ua/svit/bilya-pragi-stalasya-masshtabna-dtp-agiblih-i-mayzhe-pivsotni-poranenih-mzs-z-yasovuye-chi-ye-ukrayinci-1084945.html

Comment: + how it might work if `document.querySelector("*>h1, * p+p")` - querySelector returns first match - in this case either h1 or p+p